# Split data frame into sub data frames and recombine with one row to represent the data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an initial data frame df, I am trying to split it into multiple data frames containing only the last 30 entries of each sub-data frame defined. I now want to create a new data frame with just one value for each sub data frame (mean of all values from the 30 points).

I create sub data frames of the last 30 points for each unique value in `df['PrsNr']`

```
dfs = {k: df[df['PrsNr'] == k].iloc[-30:,:] for k in df['PrsNr'].unique()}
```

How do create just one row with the mean of all the 30 points and remerge it to create a new data frame?

This doesn't seem to work

```
dfs_1 = {k: df[df['PrsNr'] == k].iloc[-30:,:].mean() for k in df['PrsNr'].unique()}
df_1=pd.merge(dfs_1,how="right")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html) with `mean`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('PrsNr').apply(lambda x: x.tail(30).mean())
```

Comment: This will return 30 points per sub data frame. I just want one row per sub data frame where the values of all the columns are averaged from these 30 points.